# Does the sequence of groups taken from successively finding the automorphism group always eventually become constant, for finite groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, recreational-mathematics, automorphism-group

Let $G_0$ be a finite group. Define $G_n = \operatorname{Aut}(G_{n-1})$ for $n \geq 1$.

Does this sequence always eventually end up "constant"? By constant, I mean, for any finite group $G_0$, does there exist an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $G_N \cong G_{N+1} \cong G_{N+2} \cong \dots$?

---

I'm not sure how to show it generally, nor have I found a counterexample.

I've verified it for groups of order $\leq 15$, as shown below (all such groups appear somewhere in this list).

---

Write $G_1, \dots, G_n, \to H $ if $\mathrm{Aut}(G_i) \cong H$ for each $i$. If there is no arrow to the right of a group below, it means it is isomorphic to its automorphism group.

$$C_3 \to C_2 \to \{e\}$$

$$C_5 \to C_4 \to C_2 \to \{e\}$$

$$C_7, C_9, C_{14} \to C_6 \to C_2 \to \{e\}$$

$$C_8 \to C_2 \times C_2 \to S_3$$

$$C_{15} \to C_4 \times C_2 \to D_8$$

$$Q_8, A_4 \to S_4$$

$$C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \to GL(3,2) \to PGL(2,7)$$

$$C_3 \times C_3 \to GL(2,3) \to C_2 \times S_4$$

$$C_{11} \to C_{10} \to C_4 \to C_2 \to \{e\}$$

$$C_{13} \to C_{12} \to C_2 \times C_2 \to S_3$$

$$\mathrm{Dic}_3, C_2 \times C_6 \to D_{12}$$

$$D_{10} \to GA(1,5)$$

$$D_{14} \to GA(1,7)$$

where $\{e \}$ is the trivial group, $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$, $D_{2n}$ is the dihedral group of order $2n$ $\mathrm{Dic}_n$ is the dicyclic group of order $4n$, $S_n$ (resp. $A_n$) is the symmetric (resp. alternating) group on $n$ letters, $Q_8$ is the quaternion group, $GL(n,q)$, (resp. $GA(n,q)$, $PGL(n,q)$) is the general linear (resp. affine, projective general linear) group of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: This is a "famous" problem. Search for autormophism tower. Or start with [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5635/does-declaremathoperator-autaut-aut-aut-dots-autg-dots-stabilize).

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's interesting, thank you. A lot of the results there seem to deal with eventual termination after a *transfinite* number of steps - I can't see there (or anywhere that I've searched) the statement that a finite group must have its tower terminate in a *finite* number of steps. Centerless ones certainly do as per a theorem stated there. Is this known?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27861/periodic-automorphism-towers